how to transpose table in Oracle SQL
I want to transpose the following table in Oracle SQL:
FROM:



firstname
lastname
Date




Hans
Meier
1970.01.01


Hans
Meier
1970.01.02


Hans
Meier
1970.01.03


Klaus
Schmitt
1971.01.01


Klaus
Schmitt
1971.01.02


Klaus
Schmitt
1971.01.03



TO:



firstname
lastname
Date1
Date2
Date3




Hans
Meier
1970.01.01
1970.01.02
1970.01.03


Klaus
Schmitt
1971.01.01
1971.01.02
1971.01.03



Many thanks for your answers

What's the expected result if a 4th date suddenly shows up for someone?

Number the rows and then PIVOT:
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT t.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY firstname, lastname ORDER BY dt) AS rn
        FROM   table_name t)
       PIVOT(
         MAX(dt)
         FOR rn IN (
           1 AS dt1,
           2 AS dt2,
           3 AS dt3
         )
       );

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (firstname, lastname, Dt) AS
SELECT 'Hans',  'Meier',   DATE '1970-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Hans',  'Meier',   DATE '1970-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Hans',  'Meier',   DATE '1970-01-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Klaus', 'Schmitt', DATE '1971-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Klaus', 'Schmitt', DATE '1971-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Klaus', 'Schmitt', DATE '1971-01-03' FROM DUAL

Outputs:



FIRSTNAME
LASTNAME
DT1
DT2
DT3




Hans
Meier
1970-01-01 00:00:00
1970-01-02 00:00:00
1970-01-03 00:00:00


Klaus
Schmitt
1971-01-01 00:00:00
1971-01-02 00:00:00
1971-01-03 00:00:00



fiddle

Many thanks for the solution. I tried many things and then I found a quite simple solution:
I inserted an ID for date:
Then:
SELECT  firstname, lastname
, max(CASE WHEN id=1 THEN date END) AS Date1
, max(CASE WHEN id=2 THEN date END) AS date2
, max(CASE WHEN id=3 THEN date END) AS date3
GROUP BY firstname, lastname
